# What's wrong with my Word Wrap in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, word-wrap, missing-features

It's muted out

[image: screenshoot]

I was just following a lesson and even the shortcut, ALT + Z, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your question, by click manage->setting.

the feature word warp is for code, just open some code file so it will be ok

[image: screenshoot]